# How to generate Cache Pages in Magento

Tags: php, magento, caching

Cache is generated whenever a page is visited for the first time irrespective of user, and later on whenever that page is called, server returns the cache page instead of regenerating complete Page.

I wonder if their is any way to visit or call all the pages of website, so the cache pages are generated. So whenever any user visit the site for the first time, user is served with cached pages.  This helps to eliminate time for generating pages and pages are loaded faster.

Are their any tool available to crawl all pages/links of a website?

Thank You.

Comment: http://subinsb.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-crawler-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about "cache warming". There is a magento tool to give you a list of all urls

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#list-urls

But you could also parse a server log or simply generate a list from table core_url_rewrite, which might actually what they do with n98-magerun.

Then simply curl or wget all the pages....